# Foundation 6 Equalizer initial load resets height to 0, how do I prevent this?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-6

Zurb Foundation 6 Equalizer initial load resets the height of the columns to 0 before calculating the height to set all columns to. This looks bad when the page loads and the columns collapse briefly. How do I prevent this from happening? I would prefer that all columns maintain their original height, then are expanded to be taller.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just writing a script to resize the columns on load and disabled equalizer.

```
    $(window).load(function(){
//grid col equal height
 var max = 1;
        if ($(".grid-panelv2 .row.eh")) {
            $(".grid-panelv2 .row.eh .columns").each(function () {
                if ($(this).outerHeight() > max) {
                    max = $(this).outerHeight();
                }
            });
            $(".grid-panelv2 .row.eh .columns").each(function () {
                $(this).height(max);
            });
        }
});
```